# print doesn't work with mypy

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

when I use mypy in python3 method, it doesn't print anything. I use below code and it has no error.

```
def p(st : str) -> bool:
    print('hello')
    return True

p("hello")
print(10)
```

but it doen't print "hello" or "10". what is the problem?

Comment: mypy is a static type checker, it doesn't run your code for you though. If you are calling it something like `mypy my_script.py` then you might want to try `python my_script.py` instead.

Comment: but it has this error:
`File "test.py", line 1
    def p(st : str) -> bool:
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: It seems like you might not be using Python 3 then. Can you try `python3 my_script.py`?

Comment: sorry.
it works. i have a big mistake. is it needed to use `mypy test.py` before use `python3 test.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some Python code, whether you decide to check it using mypy is completely optional. If you care about type-checking your code, you can run mypy and get back a report of any errors your code contains (if any). If you don't care about type-checking your code, you can ignore the tool (since you don't need the report).

Note that all `mypy` does is give you a report. That's why doing `mypy test.py` does nothing -- it's producing a report, not actually running any code.

Currently, your code is free of type errors, so mypy will actually print out nothing at all -- the report is empty. You can see an example of the kinds of reports mypy will give you by trying to deliberately introduce a bug into your code. For example, try modifying your function so it returns a string instead of a bool. That contradicts your type signature, so mypy will flag that as an error and include it in the generated report.

To actually run your code, you will need to use the Python interpreter. Here, it seems you are writing Python 3 code, so you will need to first install and use the Python 3 interpreter. Once that's done, you can run your code on the command line by doing `python3 test.py` if you're using Mac or Linux or by doing `py -3 test.py` if you're using Windows.

Note that the Python 3 interpreter completely ignores your type annotations when it's running it. Annotations are valid Python syntax, but are basically ignored by the Python interpreter itself. Annotations exist purely as a way of letting you attach metadata to certain parts of your code that 3rd party libraries and tools can then analyze and use.